# Why do we have -1 and +1 as binary inputs instead of 0 and 1

Tags: binary, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, bias-neuron

I'm trying to get started with neural network and implement boolean functions like AND/OR.
Instead of using 0, and 1 as binary inputs, they use -1 and +1. Is there a reason why we cannot use (0, 1)?
As an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ih5Mr93E-2c

Comment: see here http://www.faqs.org/faqs/ai-faq/neural-nets/part2/, search for `Subject: Why not code binary inputs as 0 and 1? `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases there's no difference. Just use logistic function activation instead of `tanh`. In some special forms, e.g., Ising model, it could nontrivially change the parameter space though.

Answer (score 2):

If you really mean *inputs*, there is no restriction on using `{-1,1}`. You can just as easily use `{0,1}` or any other pair of real numbers (e.g., `{6,42}`) to define your True/False input values.

What may be confusing you in the charts is that `{-1,1}` are used as the *outputs* of the neurons. The reason for that, as @Memming stated, is because of the activation function used for the neuron. If `tanh` is used for the activation function, the neuron's output will be in the range (-1,1), whereas if you use a [logistic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function), its output will be in the range (0,1). Either will work for a multi-layer perceptron - you just have to define your target value (expected output) accordingly.